# Testcafe - test scenarios failed

Tags: jenkins, testing, build, automated-tests, testcafe

I have three separate test scenarios for application **Alfresco** in **.js** format. I run them locally via testcafe and run them once a day through build on **Jenkins server**. It happens that for about one month all three scenarios passed.After this time, it happens that the build ends up in error and always at a different step.

The following errors are most common -

A JavaScript error occurred on, 
The element that matches the specified selector is not visible or 
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

I attach a file containing all three scenarios + functions used in scenarios - https://ulozto.sk/file/6AiA2Zz42dbw/ses-wf-js.

Please, can anyone advise me how to prevent these errors?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify the following points. Does the error occur only on Jenkins or locally too? Does it occur in some specific part of code? Is the problem reproduced only in some specific TestCafe version?

A common advice in this case is to increase the [selector timeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#selector-timeout) and [assertion timeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#optionstimeout) properties.

Comment: Hello, the problem occurs mainly on the Jenkins server. Sometimes the problem also occurs locally. I run the test locally, and after a while it fails. On the second attempt, it pass OK. The app page may not always load correctly. Now I have version Testcafe 1.8.0, the problem also occurred with the older versions. The problem always arises in different parts of the code. Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be a TestCafe bug. If you can provide a simple example so that we can reproduce the described issue locally, please create an issue in the TestCafe repository - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md